# Can Gitlens ignore lines in the diff that starts with specific characters?

Tags: visual-studio-code, gitlens

I am using GitLens in Visual Studio Code. I need that when GitLens does the diff, it ignores certain strings that start with certain characters. In this specific case, the characters I want to ignore are "//TODO" since I'm using an extension to mark pending tasks.

Is there a way to prevent it from considering those lines as modified?